How to debug `react-contenteditable` which expects a string but got composite `object`
I'm trying to follow the craft.js basic tutorial to create a Text element with editable content. The example uses the react-contenteditable npm package to achieve this, but when I use it in my project it just keeps throwing errors that I've been unable to debug.
import React from "react";
import {Editor, Frame, Element, useNode } from "@craftjs/core";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Slider } from "@/components/ui/slider";
import { Switch } from "@/components/ui/switch";
import ContentEditable from 'react-contenteditable'
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";

export const Text = ({ text, fontSize, textAlign }: any) => {
    const {
        connectors: { connect, drag },
        actions: { setProp },
    } = useNode();
    return (
        <div ref={(ref: any) => connect(drag(ref))}>
            <ContentEditable
                html={text}
                onChange={(e) =>
                    setProp(
                        (props: any) =>
                            (props.text = e.target.value.replace(
                                /<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g,
                                "",
                            )),
                    )
                }
                tagName="p"
                className={`text-[${fontSize}px]`}
            />
        </div>
    );
};



export const Container = ({ background, padding = 0, children }: any) => {
    const {
        connectors: { connect, drag },
    } = useNode();
    return (
        <div
            style={{ margin: "5px 0", background, padding: `${padding}px` }}
            ref={(ref: any) => connect(drag(ref))}
        >
            {children}
        </div>
    );
};

export default function Craft() {
    return (
        <div className="h-screen w-screen">
            <div className="grid h-full w-full grid-flow-col grid-cols-5 grid-rows-[10rem_1fr] items-start justify-start">
                <Editor resolver={{ Text, Container }}>
                    <div className="col-span-4 row-start-2 h-full w-full bg-secondary">
                        <Frame>
                            <Element
                                is={Container}
                                padding={5}
                                background="#eee"
                                canvas
                            >
                                <Text size="small" text="Hi world!" />
                            </Element>
                        </Frame>
                    </div>
                </Editor>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

Error
The warnings always refer to the line where I first use the <ContentEditable> component within the div of the Text component I've defined.
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Posting here as I found my answer, (although I don't know why this works):
The ContentEditable component must be mounted after the the component has been rendered like this:
export const Text = ({ text, fontSize, textAlign }: any) => {
    const {
        connectors: { connect, drag },
        actions: { setProp },
    } = useNode();
    const [data, setData] = useState<null | JSX.Element>(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        setData(<ContentEditable
            html={text}
            onChange={(e) =>
                setProp(
                    (props: any) =>
                        (props.text = e.target.value.replace(
                            /<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g,
                            "",
                        )),
                )
            }
            tagName="p"
            className={`text-[${fontSize}px]`}
            style={{ fontSize: `${fontSize}px`, textAlign }}
        />)
    }, [])
    return (
        <div ref={(ref: any) => connect(drag(ref))}>
            {data}
        </div>
    );
};



